# Yes another "Argument must be a range" question

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, range, sumifs

After struggling with this formula for over an hour, I turn to SO.

`=SUMIF(indirect($A$1&"!$Q$3:Q"),indirect($A$1&"!$E$3:E"),"="&J5)`

I am getting a `Argument must be a range` error here

The approach is simple - sum up whatever corresponds with `J5` value (`CSIQ` in this case) on sheet referenced in `$A$1`

What am i missing here please?

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try (if you want to sum Q):

```
=SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT($A$1&"!Q3:Q"), INDIRECT($A$1&"!E3:E")=J5))
```

try (if you want to sum E):

```
=SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT($A$1&"!E3:E"), INDIRECT($A$1&"!Q3:Q")=J5))
```